# Magento 2 - GraphQL custom resolver that returns a list of products

Tags: magento, graphql, magento2

I'm searching for a way to build a custom resolver that returns a list of products. I've tried reading the magento code in vendor but I'm not able to reproduce it on my code.

We already have working resolvers that returns simple types like strings ora arrays.

If you can post a snippet or some website with an example it would be great

Magento version 2.3.4

Thanks